# Javascript POST request not sending data

Tags: javascript, api, request

```
function formValidation(){
    var userid = document.getElementById(usuario);
    var usermail = document.getElementById(correo);
    var userpassword = document.getElementById(contrasena);
    var userpasswordconfirm = document.getElementById(contrasena_conf)
    
    if (userpassword == userpasswordconfirm){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append("Users", userid);
        data.append("Mail", usermail);
        data.append("pwd", userpassword);
        
        xhr.open("POST", URL, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
            value: data
        }));

    else{
        window.alert("Las contraseñas no coinciden");
        userpassword.focus();
        userpasswordconfirm.focus();
        return false;
    }
    }
    
}
```

API server is receiving {"value": {}} and it is supposed to receive the user information. I don't know exactly what to put in setRequestHeader. Hope you can help me, thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide the Backend code?

Comment: Hi, you are sending a FormData to your server then I think you have to specify "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" as ContentType in "setRequestHeader". Change 
 also JSON.stringify() with "data" only; you're sending FormData, not JSON

Comment: The example has syntax errors. Please may you fix them?

Comment: Since you are using FormData, I think you do not have to JSON.stringify() it, but send the whole object and use the appropriate request header for form data.

Comment: @ale91 — FormData objects get encoded as multipart form data **with an unpredictable but mandatory boundary parameter**. They don't get URL encoded.

Comment: if you really need to send FromData as json, you can ... `value: Object.fromEntries(data.entries())` ... but why not jsut set `data = {key:value}` in the first place

Comment: The easiest way to convert your form data to JSON is probably: `JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(new FormData(form)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send the FormData object. Send only the FormData object. Do not try to be smarter than the browser about what the Content-Type of the FormData object is. Do not try to encode the data as JSON.

```
    xhr.open("POST", URL, true);
    // NO! xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhr.send(data);
```

Make sure the server side code that parses this request can handle [multipart encoded form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean).

---

> ```
>     var userid = document.getElementById(usuario);
> ```

This almost certainly wants to be:

```
var userid = document.getElementById("usuario").value;
```

Where you:

- use a string with the ID in it and not a variable (that probably has the element inside it and not the ID)
- get the value from the element instead of the whole element

---

All of your fields are plain text, so you *could* send JSON, but then you would need to construct a plain object and not a FormData object (and your server-side code would been to be prepared for JSON).

Answer (score 0):

```
function formValidation(){
var userid = document.getElementById("usuario").value;
var usermail = document.getElementById("correo").value;
var userpassword = document.getElementById("contrasena").value;
var userpasswordconfirm = document.getElementById("contrasena_conf").value;
    
    if (userpassword != userpasswordconfirm){
       window.alert("Las contraseñas no coinciden");
       userpassword.focus();
       userpasswordconfirm.focus();
       return false;
    }

    else{
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append("User", userid);
        data.append("Mail", usermail);
        data.append("Pwd", userpassword);
    
    xhr.open("POST", URL, true);
    xhr.send(data);
    }
    
}
```

Thanks for helping this quickly, everything is working now. For those who asked, the backend code for the API:

```
@app.route("/route", methods=["POST"])
def add_new_user_data():
    username = request.form.get("User")
    usermail = request.form.get("Mail")
    userpwd = request.form.get("Pwd")

    print(username, usermail, userpwd)
    if username is None:
        return "The request is null", 400
    else:
        return "ok", 200
```